# While using base64.urlsafe_b64decode in Python3, we get data ''bytes" as data type. While in NodeJS we get Buffer

Tags: node.js, python-3.x, base64

Python3

```
token = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(encoded_token)
print (type(token)) # which gives us value in <class 'bytes'>
```

NodeJS

`var URLSafeBase64 = require('urlsafe-base64')
var token = URLSafeBase64.decode(req.cookies.Token)
// here we get token output as Buffer`

How do we get same response as Python in NodeJS?

Answer (score 0):

Bytes and buffer are the same thing. Each is a list of raw bytes.

Python uses the name bytes, while JS uses buffer, which is frankly more common.

Comment: But I don't get the same response.

Comment: Can you show me what you mean by not the same response ?

Comment: Response from Python - b'\x9c\xff\xbf\x81\n>\xdxa3'

Comment: Those are identical in python the \x prefix means hexadecimal notation. So the actual byte value is 9c which is the same as the first byte in the NodeJS

Comment: Yes. Can I get the same output as Python in NodeJS?

Comment: What does the correct output look like ? Do you want the hex form of the bytes without \x?

Comment: Yes. Is it possible?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182495/discussion-between-bharat-bittu-and-pypypy).

Comment: I want the \x form of bytes like in Python in NodeJS. I want the output in NodeJS with \x